How to restore original size of multi-selected rescaled objects in Fabric.js?
I'm trying to implement an undo function with Fabric.js. I have this code:
    let groupObjects = lastAction.before._objects;
    if (groupObjects) {
      let selectionGroup = new fabric.ActiveSelection(groupObjects, { canvas: canvas });
      selectionGroup.set({ ...lastAction.before });
      selectionGroup.setCoords();
      canvas.setActiveObject(selectionGroup);
    }
    canvas.renderAll();

lastAction.before contains the value of the object or multi-selected objects before it gets' modified. Basically it was this:
lastAction = { before: fabric.util.object.clone(canvas.getActiveObjects()) }
This code works when doing an undo for positioning, but when the objects were rescaled this code only resize the selection box but not the objects within. I tried adding this to restore the individual object size but it remain the same:
      groupObjects.forEach((obj, index) => {
        let objectToRevert = canvas.getObjects().find(o => o.objectId === obj.objectId);
        objectToRevert.set({
          left: obj.left,
          top: obj.top,
          scaleX: obj.scaleX,
          scaleY: obj.scaleY,
          angle: obj.angle,
          width: obj.width,
          height: obj.height,
          flipX: obj.flipX,
          flipY: obj.flipY,
          skewX: obj.skewX,
          skewY: obj.skewY
        });
        objectToRevert.setCoords();
        
      });



Please [edit] the question to include a [mre].

Using your approach, from the second code sample, one could set the coordinates of the selected group,
found through canvas.getActiveObject()
(not canvas.getActiveObjects()):
group.set({
    left: groupBefore.left,
    top: groupBefore.top,
    scaleX: groupBefore.scaleX,
    scaleY: groupBefore.scaleY,
    angle: groupBefore.angle,
    width: groupBefore.width,
    height: groupBefore.height,
    flipX: groupBefore.flipX,
    flipY: groupBefore.flipY,
    skewX: groupBefore.skewX,
    skewY: groupBefore.skewY
});
group.setCoords();

Here's a first implementation of this, that only works if one selects a group (mot just one object)
then modifies it and never changes or cancels the selection:


const butUndo = document.querySelector('#undo');
const elWhat = document.querySelector('#what');
butUndo.onclick = undo;

function init(){
    canvas.forEachObject(function(obj, index){
        obj.objectId = 'id_' + index;
    })

    canvas.on('before:transform', function(options){
        butUndo.disabled = false;
        const group = canvas.getActiveObject();
        const groupBefore = fabric.util.object.clone(group);
        const lastAction = {
            what: options.transform.action,
            before: groupBefore,
            groupLive: group,
        };
        undoStack.push(lastAction);
        elWhat.innerText = options.transform.action;
    });

    canvas.on('before:selection:cleared', function(){
        undoStack.splice(0);
        butUndo.disabled = true;
    })
}

function undoLastAction({groupLive: group, before: groupBefore}){
    group.set({
        left: groupBefore.left,
        top: groupBefore.top,
        scaleX: groupBefore.scaleX,
        scaleY: groupBefore.scaleY,
        angle: groupBefore.angle,
        width: groupBefore.width,
        height: groupBefore.height,
        flipX: groupBefore.flipX,
        flipY: groupBefore.flipY,
        skewX: groupBefore.skewX,
        skewY: groupBefore.skewY
    });
    group.setCoords();

    canvas.renderAll();
}

const undoStack = [];
function undo(){
    const lastAction = undoStack.pop();
    undoLastAction(lastAction);

    const stackLen = undoStack.length;
    if(stackLen === 0){
        elWhat.innerText = '...';
        butUndo.disabled = true;
    }
    else{
        elWhat.innerText = undoStack[stackLen - 1].what;
    }
}

const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
const line1 = new fabric.Line().set({x1: 10, y1: 10, x2: 90, y2: 90, strokeWidth: 2, stroke: '#000'});
const line2 = new fabric.Line().set({x1: 30, y1: 10, x2: 110, y2: 90, strokeWidth: 2, stroke: '#000'});
const line3 = new fabric.Line().set({x1: 180, y1: 100, x2: 180, y2: 250, strokeWidth: 2, stroke: '#277'});
const line4 = new fabric.Line().set({x1: 200, y1: 100, x2: 200, y2: 250, strokeWidth: 2, stroke: '#277'});
const circle = new fabric.Circle({
    radius: 20, fill: 'green', left: 200, top: 210
});
const triangle = new fabric.Triangle({
    width: 20, height: 30, fill: 'blue', left: 50, top: 60
});
canvas.add(line1, line2, line3, line4, triangle, circle).renderAll();

init();
<canvas style="border: 1px solid gray" id="c" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
<button id="undo" disabled>Undo <span id="what">...</span></button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/5.3.1/fabric.min.js" integrity="sha512-CeIsOAsgJnmevfCi2C7Zsyy6bQKi43utIjdA87Q0ZY84oDqnI0uwfM9+bKiIkI75lUeI00WG/+uJzOmuHlesMA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>



Now, if the user cancels the selection, a solution based on the previous idea (and which appears to
be the natural behavior of an "undo" operation) should be able to restore the selection.
Therefore a global currentSelection is maintained and saved to the undo stack when the selection
changes.
To restore a group one will have to set not only its coordinates, but also the coordinates of its .objects.
For that I took control on the cloning process by saving/restoring only the coordinates of an object
or group (functions cloneCoords/setClonedCoords).
In order to be able to test these procedures, I had to implement what is a solution to the whole undo
process. There are many other details, which I suppose are already implemented in some way in your existing code:


const butUndo = document.querySelector('#undo');
const elWhat = document.querySelector('#what');
butUndo.onclick = undo;

function init(){
    canvas.forEachObject(function(obj, index){
        obj.objectId = 'id_' + index;
    });

    canvas.on('selection:updated', function(){
        checkSelectionForUndoStack();
        currentSelection = canvas.getActiveObject();
    })
    canvas.on('selection:created', function(...args){
        currentSelection = canvas.getActiveObject();
    })
    canvas.on('before:selection:cleared', function({target: group}){
        currentSelection = canvas.getActiveObject();
        checkSelectionForUndoStack();
    });

    canvas.on('before:transform', function(options){
        butUndo.disabled = false;
        const group = canvas.getActiveObject();
        const groupCoords = cloneCoords(group, false);
        const lastAction = {
            what: options.transform.action,
            before: groupCoords
        };
        undoStack.push(lastAction)
        elWhat.innerText = options.transform.action;
    });
}

let currentSelection = null;
function checkSelectionForUndoStack(){
    // when a selection is cleared or changed, and *it is the support of the latest transform
    // operation* in undoStack: save its deep cloned coordinates (i.e., including _objects if it's a
    // group) at the last entry in undoStack, providing the info needed to restore the selection on undo.
    if(!restoringGroup && currentSelection && undoStack.length > 0 &&
        !undoStack[undoStack.length - 1].groupToRestore){
        undoStack[undoStack.length - 1].groupToRestore = cloneCoords(currentSelection, ['objectId']);
        currentSelection = null;
    }
}

let restoringGroup = false;
function undoLastAction({before: groupCoordsBefore, groupToRestore}){
    let group;
    if(groupToRestore){
        restoringGroup = true;
        let sel;
        if(groupToRestore._objects){ // if group selection
            const groupIds = groupToRestore._objects.map(o => o.objectId);
            sel = new fabric.ActiveSelection(canvas.getObjects().filter(o => groupIds.includes(o.objectId)), {canvas});
        }
        else{ // if selection is just one object
            sel = canvas.getObjects().find(o => groupToRestore.objectId === o.objectId);
        }
        canvas.setActiveObject(sel);
        group = sel;
        setClonedCoords(group, groupToRestore);
        restoringGroup = false;
    }
    else{
        group = canvas.getActiveObject();
    }

    setClonedCoords(group, groupCoordsBefore);
    canvas.renderAll();
}

const coords = ['left', 'top', 'angle', 'scaleX', 'scaleY', 'width', 'height', 'skewX', 'skewY', 'flipX', 'flipY'];
function cloneCoords(objOrGroup, deep = false){
    const groupCoords = Object.fromEntries(
        coords.map(
            prop => [prop, objOrGroup[prop]]
        ));
    if(objOrGroup.objectId){
        groupCoords.objectId = objOrGroup.objectId;
    }
    if(deep && objOrGroup._objects){
        groupCoords._objects = objOrGroup._objects.map(obj => cloneCoords(obj, false));
    }
    return groupCoords;
}

function setClonedCoords(objOrGroup, clonedCoords){
    if(clonedCoords._objects){
        clonedCoords._objects.forEach(
            clonedObj => {
                const obj = objOrGroup._objects.find(obj => obj.objectId === clonedObj.objectId);
                setClonedCoords(obj, clonedObj);
            }
        );
    }
    clonedCoords = Object.fromEntries(
        Object.entries(clonedCoords).filter(
            ([key]) => !['_objects', 'objectId'].includes(key)
            // delete "_objects" and "objectId" keys from clonedCoords
        ));
    objOrGroup.set(clonedCoords);
    objOrGroup.setCoords();
}

const undoStack = [];
function undo(){
    const lastAction = undoStack.pop();
    undoLastAction(lastAction);

    const stackLen = undoStack.length;
    if(stackLen === 0){
        elWhat.innerText = '...';
        butUndo.disabled = true;
    }
    else{
        elWhat.innerText = undoStack[stackLen - 1].what;
    }
}

const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
const line1 = new fabric.Line().set({x1: 10, y1: 10, x2: 90, y2: 90, strokeWidth: 2, stroke: '#000'});
const line2 = new fabric.Line().set({x1: 30, y1: 10, x2: 110, y2: 90, strokeWidth: 2, stroke: '#000'});
const line3 = new fabric.Line().set({x1: 180, y1: 100, x2: 180, y2: 250, strokeWidth: 2, stroke: '#277'});
const line4 = new fabric.Line().set({x1: 200, y1: 100, x2: 200, y2: 250, strokeWidth: 2, stroke: '#277'});
const circle = new fabric.Circle({
    radius: 20, fill: 'green', left: 200, top: 210
});
const triangle = new fabric.Triangle({
    width: 20, height: 30, fill: 'blue', left: 50, top: 60
});
canvas.add(line1, line2, line3, line4, triangle, circle).renderAll();
<canvas style="border: 1px solid gray" id="c" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
<button id="undo" disabled>Undo <span id="what">...</span></button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/5.3.1/fabric.min.js" integrity="sha512-CeIsOAsgJnmevfCi2C7Zsyy6bQKi43utIjdA87Q0ZY84oDqnI0uwfM9+bKiIkI75lUeI00WG/+uJzOmuHlesMA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>



or as jsFiddle

You're on the right track with the approach you're taking. It looks like the main issue lies in how you're trying to restore the scale of individual objects. The code for restoring positioning and angles seems fine, but Fabric.js handles scaling, width, and height in a specific way, which is why simply setting these properties might not be giving the desired results.
Here’s the breakdown of why it might not be working as expected and how you can fix it:
Problem:
When you try to restore the individual object's size by setting width, height, scaleX, and scaleY, Fabric.js handles these properties in a more interdependent way. Specifically:
Width and Height are usually fixed once an object is created. If you try to change them later, especially in combination with scaling, it can lead to incorrect results because Fabric.js uses the scaling values (scaleX, scaleY) to determine the object’s size relative to its original width/height.
Solution:
Instead of modifying both width/height and scaleX/scaleY, it’s better to focus on just restoring the scaling and not touch the width and height of the object. Also, you need to ensure that these changes propagate properly by calling setCoords() and re-rendering the canvas afterward.
Here’s how you can adjust your code:
Updated Solution:
groupObjects.forEach((obj, index) => {
  // Find the current object in the canvas that matches the one you want to revert
  let objectToRevert = canvas.getObjects().find(o => o.objectId === obj.objectId);
  
  // Restore position, scale, and other transformations
  objectToRevert.set({
    left: obj.left,
    top: obj.top,
    scaleX: obj.scaleX,  // Restore scaling
    scaleY: obj.scaleY,  // Restore scaling
    angle: obj.angle,    // Restore rotation
    flipX: obj.flipX,    // Restore flipping
    flipY: obj.flipY,    // Restore flipping
    skewX: obj.skewX,    // Restore skewing
    skewY: obj.skewY     // Restore skewing
  });

  // Important: Do not modify `width` and `height`, as scale already takes care of it
  
  // Recalculate object boundaries and coordinates
  objectToRevert.setCoords();
});

// Re-render the canvas to apply all changes
canvas.renderAll();

